# How to ignore the zero value to calculate the mean in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import statistics
import numpy as np

names = ['place', 'age', 'NoMale', 'NoFemale', 'DNoMale', 'DNoFemale']
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', names=names)
SData = df.groupby('place')['NoMale', 'NoFemale', 'DNoMale', 'DNoFemale'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by=['place'],axis=0,ascending=True, inplace=False)

SData["MaleFRates"] = SData['NoMale']/SData['DNoMale']
SData["FemaleFRates"] = SData['NoFemale']/SData['DNoFemale']
SData_sorted= SData.sort_values('MaleFRates', )

plt.barh(SData_sorted['place'],SData_sorted[ 'MaleFRates'])

print(SData)

mean = [SData_sorted[ 'MaleFRates'] != 0].SData_sorted[ 'MaleFRates'].mean()

print(mean)
```

I want to get the mean of the death rate in the different places but there is an zero value, how can i remove it

Get the mean of the death rate ignoring the zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = [("A", 10), ("B", 0), ("C", 20)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Value"])
print(df)

sub_df = df.where(df["Value"] != 0)
print(sub_df)
print(sub_df.mean())
```

where the application of `where` and a condition are used to remove a `0` value from the data. So in the specific case that you mentioned,

```
SData_sorted.where(SData_sorted['MaleFRates'] != 0).mean()
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
mean = SData_sorted[SData_sorted[ 'MaleFRates'] != 0]['MaleFRates'].mean()
```

your syntax is incorrect...

Answer (score 2):

I believe it also depends on the significance of '0' values.

1. If they are literally '0', then

   ```
   df = SData_sorted[SData_sorted[ 'MaleFRates'] != 0]]
   print(df.mean())
   ```
2. If they are values are not measured, you can replace '0's with `NaN`.

   ```
   df = SData_sorted.replace(0, np.NaN)
   print(df.mean())
   ```

   By default `mean` ignores `NaN` values

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to ignore the zero value. It's not taken into account when the mean is calculated. But if you want to remove zeros from a specific column you can try

```
SData_sorted.loc[~(SData_sorted['MaleFRates'] == 0)]
```